# Capture API works bad in dark especially in night time or in previewing dark corners through camera

Tags: swift, avfoundation, cosmicmind, avcam

I was using this library which is https://github.com/CosmicMind/Material. Everything is already working well aside from one which requires a bit of optimization,

I've tried this one which works pretty well with improved lighting in the dark, it is pretty much useful for devices that don't have flash such as iPads.

https://github.com/ooper-shlab/AVCamManual-Swift

I can't seem to get where the lighting optimization happens in the code. I would've help if I have figured out.

The preview really would look a lot darker using the Capture API of material.

Screenshots of each can be seen below:
The demo for Material's Capture Api:
[image: Cosmicmind's Capture demo]

The demo for AVFoundation:[image: AVCamManual Demo screenshot]

Comment: Yes, there is a known issue with the Capture API being dark as you described. It is in the queue for a rewrite to fix known issues. Sorry for the inconvenience on this :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after trying to do some trial and error on the code of AVFoundation. 
Commenting codes until I could see which block of code is responsible for the lighting. 
I was able to find out that it was the AVCaptureSession.sessionPreset which was originally set to  = AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh, after setting it to

AVCaptureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto

Now it's better and looks like the default on ios camera app.

Comment: I updated the default value to the .presetPhoto so this issue will be avoided in the future. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Based on the given answer above by @Jojo Narté, the correct usage of the API would be to set the `Capture.capturePreset value to .presetPhoto`.